# cuda integration in a C++ file

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I've read all relative subjects on including a `.cu` file into a `.cpp` files written before by others, but nothing helps me.

I've a problem for including files in C++ files of my project.
My project structure is as follows: `main.cpp` `compute.h` `compute.cpp` `kernel.cu`.

`main.cpp` has more than the entry main() point of my project. Several `_host_` cuda functions, and it includes `compute.h` because it calls some functions defined in compute.h.

`compute.cpp` has only `C++` functions, using a `sum<<<1,numbloc>>>(list of parameters)` function, which refers to the `kernel.cu` device code. Then I've included `kernel.cu` in the `compute.cpp` headers. But I've problem while compiling on my visual studio 2008 with cuda 5.0, and the error says

```
error C3861:'_syncthreads':identifier not found
```

but when I write a projetc with a single `main.cu` containing `main(){}` and my `_host_` functions, it builds without errors.

Can I keep my project structure as described above, and run without error my project? please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a .cpp file cannot contain anything that is not ordinary C/C++ syntax.  A cuda kernel call `kernel<<<...>>>()` cannot be in a .cpp file, unless you pass special switches to nvcc.

So the usual recommendation is to rename any file that uses CUDA in this way to have a .cu extension instead of a .cpp extension, and compile that file with nvcc.

The same applies for any CUDA-specific syntax.  (Note that this does not mean calls to the CUDA API, such as `cudaMalloc`, which can be done in an ordinary .cpp file if you include cuda_runtime.h and link properly.)  Therefore, if you actually have the `__host__` function decorator in your main.cpp, that also would not work (using default compiler settings).

Comment: Thanks, U're right. I've put all my callers functions `<<<>>>` in `.cu` files, and their related `_global_` functions too.

Comment: However, I've in the same `.cu` file,  `__device__ int  compute(int a, int b){...}` and `int compute(int a, int b){...}`. The first one is only for device, and the second is a `__host__` function. but I get the error `error: function "compute" has already been defined`. How can I fix this problem please?

Comment: You can't define two functions with the same name, even if one is host and one is device.  Either change the names of the two functions so they are different, or combine them both into a single function that has both the `__host__` and `__device__` decorators.  If you need to do something different depending on whether it is running on the host or device, there is a compile macro for that.

Comment: thanks, I've just rename my functions and it works fine! thanks a lot.

Comment: Does nvcc care about the extension used on a source code file? If you simply called nvcc with a .cu file but named it .cpp will it try to compile it as c++ code only?

Comment: Yes, nvcc cares about the extensions used on a source file.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Hi, please, look at my post question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090950/cuda-passing-user-defined-structure-to-a-kernel-failed) and let me know what you're thinking about.