# cuda passing user defined structure to a kernel failed

Tags: c++, c, cuda

Here is my problem. I have the following structure in my `kernel.h`.

```
struct   __Q_VECTOR__{
    double* Data;       
    int     Dimension;  
    int     Cluster;    
};

typedef struct __Q_VECTOR__     VQ_VECTOR;
```

In the `kernel.cu` I have the following code

```
int main(void){
 int L = 3, //.Data length
    N = 100;

VQ_VECTOR   *A,
            *device_VQ_VECTOR;

cudaError_t cudaStatus;

A =   (VQ_VECTOR*)malloc(N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    VQ_VECTOR a;
    a.Data = (double*)malloc(L*sizeof(double));;
    a.Cluster   =   1;
    a.Dimension =   L;
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        a.Data[j]=i*j;

    A[i] = a;
}

//Prinf of all the elements of A
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    printf("\nA[%d]={");
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        printf("%.3f",A[i].Data[j]);
    printf("}");
}

printf("\n\n");
//I Allocate and Copy data from A to device_VQ_VECTORon the GPU memory

cudaDeviceReset();
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_VQ_VECTOR, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(device_VQ_VECTOR, A, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaPrintfInit();
testKernel<<<N,1>>>(device_VQ_VECTOR, N);//to test and see on a sigle thread
cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);
cudaPrintfEnd();
cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n testKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        return 1;
}
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(A, device_VQ_VECTOR, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n testKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        return 1;
}
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    printf("\nA[%d]={");
    for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
        printf("%.3f",A[i].Data[j]);
    printf("}");
}
cudaFree(device_VQ_VECTOR);
 return 0;
```

}

when I build, sometimes it prints nothing, sometimes it works.
what's wrong in my code? May be caused by

```
cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_VQ_VECTOR, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(device_VQ_VECTOR, A, N* sizeof(VQ_VECTOR), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Help please!

Comment: I've tried                                                                                        `cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_VQ_VECTOR, N* sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
  cudaMalloc((void**)&(device_VQ_VECTOR[i].Data), X[i].nDimension * sizeof(double));`                                                                without succes too

Comment: Do you allocate memory for `data`? Add that to question. And please post complete compilable example, the one in question clearly have syntax errors.

Comment: @keltar I've not allocated memory for `Data`,  because I think it's suposed to be performed by the 2 operations `cudaMalloc((void**)&device_VQ_VECTOR, N* sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));` and `cudaMemcpy(device_VQ_VECTOR, A, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`  Isn't it?

Comment: Depends on your definition. It wouldn't allocate memory, but will assign `Data` to the same pointer it was in `A` (which is still bad idea). If even `A` didn't got it's `Data` allocation, - well, that is obviously cannot work reliably.

Comment: @keltar    I've edited the example, you can compile and run it. I want it to printf the .Data elements from the device pointer parameter, but it doesn't.

Comment: @kelta A is well allocated, as you can see. (try to run my example code please). Nevertheless , nothing works, but I cant print other things inside the `__global__` function,.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work because arrays are allocated separately, and not copied into device memory. You need to allocate them on device too, and make full copy. To make it worse, you cannot access device memory from host side directly (other way than `cudaMemcpy`), so you can't use e.g. `cudaMalloc(&device_VQ_VECTOR[i].Data, ...)` (it will crash).

Here is an example code. For simplicity sake, it drops host-side `A[i].Data` and then re-creates them. It isn't too good, but that will go.

```
struct   __Q_VECTOR__{
    double* Data;       
    int     Dimension;  
    int     Cluster;    
};

typedef struct __Q_VECTOR__     VQ_VECTOR;

__global__ void testKernel(VQ_VECTOR *X, int N){
    int i= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    cuPrintf("\n testKernel entrance by the global threadIdx= %d\n", i);
    for(int k=0; k<X[i].Dimension; k++)
        cuPrintf("%2.2f, ",X[i].Data[k]);
    cuPrintf("\n");
}

int main(void){
    int L = 3, //.Data length
        N = 100;

    VQ_VECTOR   *A,
                *device_VQ_VECTOR;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    A =   (VQ_VECTOR*)malloc(N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        VQ_VECTOR a;
        a.Data = (double*)malloc(L*sizeof(double));;
        a.Cluster   =   1;
        a.Dimension =   L;
        for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
            a.Data[j]=(1+i)*(1+j);

        A[i] = a;
    }

    //Prinf of all the elements of A
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("\nA[%d]={", i);
        for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
            printf("%.3f",A[i].Data[j]);
        printf("}\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    //I Allocate and Copy data from A to device_VQ_VECTORon the GPU memory

    cudaDeviceReset();
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_VQ_VECTOR, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR));
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(device_VQ_VECTOR, A, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        /* can't access device_VQ_VECTOR[i].Data directly from host-side,
         * working around it with proxy variable */
        double *out;
        cudaMalloc(&out, L*sizeof(double));
        cudaMemcpy(out, A[i].Data, L*sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(&device_VQ_VECTOR[i].Data, &out, sizeof(void*),
                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        // will re-allocate later, for simplicity sake
        free(A[i].Data);
    }

    cudaPrintfInit();
    testKernel<<<N,1>>>(device_VQ_VECTOR, N);//to test and see on a sigle thread
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n testKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        return 1;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(A, device_VQ_VECTOR, N*sizeof(VQ_VECTOR), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        // allocate array, copy data
        double *array = (double*)malloc(L*sizeof(double));
        cudaMemcpy(array, A[i].Data, L*sizeof(double),
                cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        // assign new array to A[i]
        A[i].Data = array;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n testKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        return 1;
    }
/*  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        printf("\nA[%d]={", i);
        for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
            printf("%.3f",A[i].Data[j]);
        printf("}\n");
    }*/
    cudaFree(device_VQ_VECTOR);

    // don't forget to free A and all its Data

    return 0;
}
```

Part of output would be (it is huge, I don't want to post too much):

```
[2, 0]: 3.00, [18, 0]: 19.00, [22, 0]: 23.00, [16, 0]: 17.00,
[24, 0]: 25.00, [19, 0]: 20.00, [4, 0]: 5.00, [23, 0]: 24.00,
[3, 0]: 4.00, [5, 0]: 6.00, [13, 0]: 14.00, [1, 0]: 2.00,
[10, 0]: 11.00, [6, 0]: 7.00, [14, 0]: 15.00, [0, 0]: 1.00, [20, 0]:
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the results, all the `VQ_VECTOR` elements of the `device_VQ_VECTOR` pointer array have their `Data` values to `0`. I've tried to print the `Data` elements of `device_VQ_VECTOR[i]` and all the values are set to 0. Here is my modified `global` function you can replace to test

Comment: Print nothing than 0. It seems `deviceQV_VECTOR` doesn't contains true values

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with zero values. Values are set to `i*j`, so with i or j eq to 0 it will be 0 of course. If you have problem, please add an example to your question (with edit - add, not replace).

Comment: use this as a `__testkernel__` function, and see results

Comment: `int i= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  cuPrintf("\n testKernel entrance by the global threadIdx= %d\n", i); for(int k=0; k<X[i].Dimension; k++)
     cuPrintf("%2.2f, ",X[i].Data[k]);
    cuPrintf("\n");
} `

Comment: my kernel function prints all the values, but I wonder why they are all set to 0

Comment: For test's purpose change array initialisation to `(1+i)*(1+j)`, you probably hitting zero rows/columns. Otherwise there are a lot of zeroes, as it should be, but surely not all of them.

Comment: I've donne what you said, and here is the output of the kernel: `testKernel entrance by the global threadIdx= 0
[0, 0]: 0.00, [0, 0]: 0.00, [0, 0]: 0.00, [0, 0]:
[1, 0]:
 testKernel entrance by the global threadIdx= 1
[1, 0]: 0.00, [1, 0]: 0.00, [1, 0]: 0.00, [1, 0]:
[2, 0]:
 testKernel entrance by the global threadIdx= 2
[2, 0]: 0.00, [2, 0]: 0.00, [2, 0]: 0.00, [2, 0]:
` and so on, from the first to the 99th thread

Comment: (How can I well format my comments to set code by the comment?)

Comment: I'll edit my code, and add the output in to show what I'm compiling and running since

Comment: nothing else? still without accceptable results. all threads of my kernel prints only `0` value

Comment: You said "I'll edit my code, and add the output in to show what I'm compiling and running since". So far I see no edits.

Comment: I've tried for many times but the code editors refused to save my edition. Nevertheless, the output is shown in my referenced commend above, since 3hours., after you told me to put in array initialization the values `(1+i)*(1+j)`. That's what i did

Comment: Not sure. Verify that you run exactly the same code; I'll edit my answer to integrate initialisation and kernel code. Works for me, but it might be unavailable on pre-dx10 hardware, if that is the case (don't really know about that, just may be).

Comment: nothing new. can you please modifiy the array initialization to `(1+i)*(1+j)`  and post your output results and the related code?

Comment: But it is `(1+i)*(1+j)`. Added part of output. With that formula there wouldn't be (or at least shouldn't be) any single zero in array.

Comment: According to me, my output doesn't changed, even with your edited code that I've built and run. May be a problem of my nvidia architecture?